# Node.js Middleware block the program, why program is disable to run?

Tags: node.js, express

```
const express = require('express');
const fs = require('fs');

const app = express();

app.set('view engine', 'hbs');
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

// MIDDLEWARE 2
app.use((req, res, next) => {
  res.render('test');
});

//MIDDLEWARE 3
app.use((req, res, next) => {
  let now = new Date().toString();
  let log = `At ${now} a peroson visited ${req.method} ${req.url}`;
  console.log(log);
  fs.appendFile('visitors.log', log + '\n', err =>{
    if(err) return err;
  });
  next();
});


app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.send(index.html);
});


app.get('/about', (req, res) => {
  res.render('about', {
    title: 'About Us'
  });
});




app.listen(3000, () => {
  console.log('Server is running on port 3000')
});
```

I am expecting my middleware 2 to block all other routes but my other routes are just working fine. Is there any bug with my code or what I am learning is no longer valid?

Comment: The question doesn't contain the problem that could be replicated by other users. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve and https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask . *I am expecting my middleware 2 to block all other routes but my other routes are just working fine.* - that's very unlikely, as long as your code conforms to the code that you posted. 'middleware 2' creates a response and doesn't call `next()`. Other middlewares besides `express.static` have no chances to run. End of the story.

Comment: @estus maybe you must inform, describe, solve it in answer not comment because your answer is correct.

Comment: @elia At this point there's nothing to answer because the question wasn't asked correctly and falls into off-topic category. The OP asks about the behaviour that don't exist in the code that was posted.

Comment: @estus "Other middlewares besides express.static have no chances to run" clarify my understanding. I was accessing ' / '  worked fine because middleware that save static files is on top of middleware 2. Thank you

Comment: Glad this helped.

Answer (score 0):

After the `res.render`, you need to call `next()`